# Error401 al hacer get http?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer una aplicación con Angular y al hacer un `get request` a la API (que también estoy  construyendo con spring boot).
La api está protegida, tiene jwt.

Me permite loguearme, me devuelve json token, pero no me autoriza a los metodos del controler de la api, tienen la notation @CrossOrigin. Controlé las rutas de acceso, y son correctas.
Pruebo con postman y funciona bien.
Alguna idea?

Así está compuesta mi clase controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class controler {
    @Autowired
    private IPersonaService persoServ;
    
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping ("/new/persona")
    public void 
    agregarPersona(@RequestBody persona 
    pers){
    persoServ.crearPersona(pers);
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/ver/personas")
    @ResponseBody
    public List <persona> verPersonas(){
      return persoServ.verPersonas();
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public void borrarPersona 
   (@PathVariable Long id){
    persoServ.borrarPersona(id);
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/buscar/persona/{id}")
    public persona 
    buscarPersona(@PathVariable Long id){
    return persoServ.buscarPersona(id);
    }
}
```

Este es el servicio que hace la petición en Angular

```
import { HttpClient } from'@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Persona } from '../model/persona.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonaService {
url:string = 'http://localhost:8080';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getPersona(): Observable<Persona>{
  //pruebas con distintas rutas
   // return this.http.get<Persona>
    //('../../assets/data/data.json')
   // return this.http.get<Persona>(this.url +'/ver/personas')//
return this.http.get<Persona>(this.url + '/buscar/persona/1')
  }
}
```

Este es el servicio interceptor

```
    import { AutenticacionService } from './autenticacion.service';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

   constructor(private autenticacionService:AutenticacionService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    var currentUser= this.autenticacionService.usuarioAutenticado;
  if(currentUser && currentUser.accesToken){
//se clona el req para agregar el token al encabezado //
    req=req.clone({
     setHeaders:{Authorization: "Bearer ${token}"}
    });
    console.log(req)
  }

  console.log('el servicio de interceptor esta corriendo' + JSON.stringify(currentUser))
  return next.handle(req)
}
}
```

este es el app-module

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({}),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ {provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi:true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

el error al inspeccionar es este...

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8080/buscar/persona/1', ok: false, …}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes.Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Cuántas formas diferentes puede haber de implementar bien esos requests? Muchísimas. Cuántas habrá de hacerlo con errores? Muchas más. Qué puede estar fallando? Cualquier cosa! Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: gracias, soy nueva en SOes, seguire tus consejos. subo los codigos...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401 xd

Comment: Encontré el problema. Estaba en la api. Solo permitía el acceso a "*/Auth/*". Lo modifiqué por "**", para poder acceder a todos los métodos.